# Entity Reference field using View to Mask Autocomplete with Last Name

Tags: entities

I've posted about this here as well: http://drupal.org/node/1906344

I'm trying to use an Entity Reference field to reference users with a last name field I created on a "Product Page" content type.

You see, whenever you try to reference a user, you're forced to do so with the username. So to get around this, you have to create a view that outputs the last name field from the profile and then use that view in a way that accepts an argument to key off of (i.e. - the last name).

I've created my view and on the views page, this view works. But when I use the "Filter by an entity reference view" to attach my view, I discover that it doesn't work on the node-add page. I'll start typing a last name that's associated with a registered user and, well, nothing comes up. The reference type I indicated in the "Target type" is user and the view isn't anything special: it's just an "Entity Reference" view type set to accept 1 contextual filter (the last name) and subsequently outputs the respective users if that argument matches the last name field value(s). So I don't know what's going on here...

Here's my basic setup:
- Drupal 7.x
- Entity API 7.x-1.0
- Entity Connect 7.x-1.0-beta2
- Entity Reference 7.x-1.0
- Views 7.x-3.5

I'm using Entity Connect to provide the ability to create the user if he or she doesn't exist. Otherwise, the field *should* reference something--which it currently doesn't.

Any help on this is appreciated and please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Sorry to see your question was not answered. Did you ever get it working?

Comment: @marcvangend Looks like he did, based on https://www.drupal.org/node/1906344#comment-7023524

Answer (score 1):

Remove the contextual filter from your Entity Reference view.

The view should have **all** the available options. The autocomplete widget for the Entity Reference field will filter the available options based on the user input. If you change the widget type to "Check boxes/radio buttons" you can see the available options which may help diagnose the issue.